# Can software legally collect information on it's users without disclosing that it is doing so?

Tags: software, traffic, data-ownership, sweden

I am a software engineer and I am currently working with a little bit of software security related research.

The project I am working with touches the subject of Computer Game Cheating Software (hereon referred to as "GCS").

Our company is trying to form ideas on how to bring the future of Anti-Cheat systems closer to the present time to enhance the gaming experience for millions of people around the world.

We do so by disassembling, decompiling and analyzing GCS , as well as analyzing network traffic that is sent and received by the GCS.

We were banned from a specific GCS site because of the following reason:

> Attempting to sniff network traffic / disassembling / decompile / debug GCS

The software itself notified us with the following message (or similar) upon login:

> Your attempt has been logged

What we did next was to create a new account and purchase the GCS again.

I could not get it to work so I contacted their live support, upon which they were very rude and played mental games with me because they noticed that I was the same person trying to get their software up and running again.

Obviously they assumed that we was going to try to sniff the network traffic again, which of course we will, and they can't do anything about it and they don't like that.

I was also threatened with legal actions for trying to reverse engineer their software, which does not make any sense, because they have done the same thing themselves in order to create the GCS.

We've discovered that their software has been monitoring the activity on our computer without letting us know about it.

Their software does not contain any EULA which states what information it collects, sends or receives.

They are obviously operating as a company, generating profit, running customer support etc.

We know what we are doing and we also know that **their software collecting information illegally**.

What can we as a company do about this in terms of legal issues?

Comment: Let me get this straight. Your company wants to develop anti-cheating software. To do this, you are analyzing cheating software to develop countermeasures and are upset that they are trying to block you from doing this? Your software would essentially put them out of business, no? It makes perfect sense that they would try to prevent you from doing what you are doing. In order to answer your question, we need to know what laws apply to you. Where is your business located? Where do you plan to sell your software (I'm assuming worldwide)?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. That is not the case. We are not upset. You have not got us straight at all. Their software collects information from our computer which we have not been informed about. THAT is our issue.
We are located in Sweden. Yes, our market is World Wide.

Comment: So is your question basically "can we sue them?" or is it "is it illegal for software to collect information off of a computer on which I knowingly installed the software, but the software never disclosed to me that it was going to collect said information?"

Comment: By the way, your question in the title "Can we be stopped from sniffing network traffic?" appears to be very different from what you are asking in the body.

Comment: It is both. I'm sorry for any confusion again. Can I change the title? or is it too late?

Comment: Use the [edit](https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/10795/edit) link and you should be able to edit the title and/or the body.

Comment: @mikeazo what would you suggest to be the proper title? Something like "Are they allowed to collect data from us without disclosure?".

Comment: How about "Can software legally collect information on it's users without disclosing that it is doing so?". I would also suggest adding the [tag:Sweden] tag to the question.